# (Altium) Multi-Channel Design - Net-Names don't change and how to use Harness?

Tags: altium

I have a circuit which I want to use 3 times in my project. So, I thought it would be nice to try multi-channel design function in AD. I read the oline documentation and it seems to work (I used the repeat function) but I have 2 problems:

1. My component designators get the right naming (R11_1, R11_2. R11_3) but my net names are still all same. In the online documentation the net-names also change. My question is how I can fix this problem?
2. My 2nd problem is, how I can use multi-channel design with harness?  I couldn't find any information in the online documentation. Maybe I need to use multiple sheet-symbols, so I have 3 harness-ports but again the naming of the would not change.

i will attach 2 pictures:

[image: this is how I made the multi-channel]

[image: Problem with net-names naming]

Answer (score 1):

Every component in the sub-circuits will get a suffix _1, _2..., but the signals remain the same, you basically share the same signal among those 3 sub-circuits. Maybe it is better to use individual wire signal instead of harness.